# TPT load data type error

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to run a TPT load, but I am getting an error with my date datatype. Can someone help me with the right syntax?

```
DEFINE JOB MOVE_DATA
DESCRIPTION 'MOVE DATA'
(DEFINE SCHEMA SAMPLE_SCHEMA DESCRIPTION 'SAMPLE SCHEMA'
(     
      CUST DECIMAL(15,0) ,
      START_DATE DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' 
);
```

> Error: TPT_INFRA: At "DATE" missing { PERIOD_ ANSIDATE_ BIGINT_ BLOB_
>   BYTE_ BYTEINT_ CHARACTER_ CHAR_ CHARACTERS_ CHARS_ CLOB_ DEC_ DECIMAL_
>   FLOAT_ GRAPHIC_ INT_ INTDATE_ INTEGER_ INTERVAL_ LONG_ NUMBER_
>   NUMERIC_ SMALLINT_ TIME_ TIMESTAMP_ VARBYTE_ VARCHAR_ VARDATE_
>   VARGRAPHIC_ XML_ } in Rule: Column Data Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATE` is not a supported field type for your `SCHEMA` in a TPT. You can use `VARCHAR(10)`. For Example:

```
START_DATE VARCHAR(10)
```

Or if you need to do a change of format in the TPT ETL, you can use `VARDATE()`. For example:

```
START_DATE VARDATE(10) FORMATIN ('YYYY-MM-DD') FORMATOUT ('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also found that ANSIDATE worked for this.

Comment: ANSIDATE! That's cool. I haven't tried that yet. Almost all of our ETL just sticks every field in a VARCHAR. I just recently started using VARDATE() to adjust incoming date formats. It's very handy for `m/d/yyyy` formats that don't have a leading 0.